# How can I optimize images uploaded using Paperclip & Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Does anyone know how to optimize image size through paperclip?

In my Graphic model I have the following:

```
has_attached_file :graphic, 
                    :styles => {
                      :home       => ['120x90',:jpg],
                      :thumb      => ['70x70',:jpg]
                    }
```

By optimize I mean, reduce the filesize of each of :home & :thumb graphics once paperclip creates them, Google's speed test tells me that I should be able to reduce these by 70 - 90%.

I think I can do this by creating a perclip processor, but not really sure where to start.

Kind of stumped on this one, any help / hints much appreciated!

(Rails 2.3)

Comment: You might want to be more specific. Are you running into a problem? Can you post some code? What kind of image optimization are you looking to perform?

Comment: @Pan, updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: check out my blog post. http://www.ror-e.com/posts/6-optimize-your-images this should help.

Answer (score 3):

There's a gem that allows you to do this easily with Paperclip:

https://github.com/janfoeh/paperclip-optimizer

Answer (score 2):

And this gem to image compression processor for Paperclip:

https://github.com/emrekutlu/paperclip-compression

Answer (score 1):

Check out the quality option. I've read that 75 is the best setting for balancing quality and the resulting size of the image.

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles => {
                  :small => {
                    :geometry => '38x38#',
                    :quality => 40,
                    :format => 'JPG'
                  },
                  :medium => {
                    :geometry => '92x92#',
                    :quality => 50
                  }
```